# Password validation failing after error displayed using VUE & rexex

Tags: regex, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `vue` app and I have a change password page which I am trying to add validation to my new password `input`.

the condition is one or more of

- Any special char except space
- Uppercase letter
- Number
- Min 6 digits
- Max 15 digits

I have the following `regex`

```
let nwPwChars = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{6,15}$/;
```

The issue I am having is, if I enter 'Password00!' for the first time in the `input` it validates and works fine but if I enter `abc` then tab out, it fails my validation and displays my error message but then if I continue to hit all my conditions after this (acbd01!) it's still failing my validation as looking at my console soon as it hits 6 it returns `null`
[image]

Doing it the first time without failing passes

[image]

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-4">
            <label for="newPw">New password <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="newPw" ref="newPw" v-model="newPw" class="form-control" :class="newPwMatchChecker" :type="newPwFieldType" @input="newPWValCheck_1" @blur="newPWValCheck_2"
                        @paste.prevent placeholder="Enter your new password">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn input-group-text" type="button" @click="showHideNewPw" :disabled="this.newPw.length === 0" tabindex="-1">
                        <i class="far" :class="newPwImg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="nwPwError" class="form-group" style="margin-top: -10px">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="text-danger">The password entered does not match the criteria above. Please try again.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-4">
            <label for="confirmNewPw">Confirm new password <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="confirmNewPw" ref="confirmNewPw" v-model="confirmNewPw" class="form-control" :class="confirmPwMatchChecker" :type="confirmNewPwFieldType"
                        :disabled="disableConfirmPwInput" @paste.prevent placeholder="Confirm your new password">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn input-group-text" type="button" @click="showHideConfirmNewPw" :disabled="this.newPw.length === 0" tabindex="-1">
                        <i class="far" :class="confirmNewPwImg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="confirmPwError" class="row mt-1">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="text-danger">The passwords entered do not match. Please try again.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**VUE code**

```
computed: {
    newPwMatchChecker() {
        if (this.nwPwError) {
            this.$refs.newPw.focus();

            return 'error';
        } else if (this.newPwValidated) {
            return 'mathced';
        }

        return ''
    },

    confirmPwMatchChecker() {
        this.confirmPwError = false;
        
        if (this.confirmNewPw.length === this.newPw.length && this.confirmNewPw != this.newPw) {
            this.confirmPwError = true;
            this.$refs.confirmNewPw.focus();

            return 'error';
        } else if (this.confirmNewPw.length >= 6 && this.confirmNewPw === this.newPw) {
            return 'matched';
        }

        return ''
    },
},

method: {
    newPWValCheck_1(e) {
        let input = e.target;

        let nwPwChars = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{6,15}$/;
        this.nwPwError = false;
        input.classList.remove('error');
        this.confirmPwError = false;
        this.confirmNewPw = '';

        console.log('1', this.newPw.length)
        console.log('2', this.newPw.length >= 6)
        console.log('3', this.newPw.length <= 15)
        console.log('4', this.newPw.match(this.nwPwChars))
        console.log('5', (this.newPw.length >=6 && this.newPw.length <= 15) && this.newPw.match(nwPwChars))
        console.log('6', this.newPw.length >=6 && this.newPw.length <= 15 && this.newPw.match(nwPwChars))
        
        if ((this.newPw.length >=6 && this.newPw.length <= 15) && this.newPw.match(nwPwChars)) {
            this.newPwValidated = true;
        } else {
            this.newPwValidated = false;
        }
    },

    newPWValCheck_2() {
        if (!this.newPwValidated) {
            this.nwPwError = true;
        } else {
            this.nwPwError = false;
        }
    }
}
```

First time entering a password which matches conditions enables my confirm `input`
[image]

Fail `regex` on the first time (only entered 3chars) displays the error as expected
[image]

Then continue typing a password to match conditions should pass but doesn't, it re-displays my error again
[image]

Comment: Your regex at the beginning is not the same you showed in the VUE code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'll be honest I got that from a website as I am no good with `regex`. All I looked for was `[a-z,A-Z,0-9]` and allows special chars

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, you life would be much simpler testing each condition separately. Sometimes the best solution isn't a huge pattern that ends up being more computationally expensive anyways.

Comment: I'm a sucker for writing these things myself, but I agree with @Bren, this RegEx sure looks cool, but who the hell knows what it does, without spending hours and hours.
I would go with something like `Joi` for this kind of validation.

Comment: Hi, @murday1983, this line `((this.newPw.length >=6 && this.newPw.length <= 15) is redundant as the regex already checks for that.

Comment: There's also a typo in the computed property `newPwMatchChecker` which returns ` `mathced` instead of `matched`. Fix that and let me know if that solves the problem.